# Issue with retrieving image from mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have used the following code before uploading an image into mysql database

Before encoding I have also done

```
$content = addslashes($content);
    $content = base64_encode($content);
```

Then after that I have tested the image in database it was entered fine.

But, whenever I try to download the same image it saves is well on the filesystem but never let me view it. As, it give me incorrect image file. Why is it so?

```
  $file_data= $this->get_attachment($id);
            $content = $file_data['content'];
                $content = stripslashes($content);
            $content =  base64_decode();
            header("Content-length: ". strlen($content));
            header("Content-type: ".$file_data['filetype']);
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_data['filename']);
            echo $content;
```

Comment: What is the data type of the MySQL column you're storing the base64 strings in? If it is varchar rather than TEXT or BLOB, you may have truncation.

Comment: ... and depending on the size there can be truncation with TEXT and BLOB as well.

Comment: I have used LongBLOB so basically it's not a truncation issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the file length of the base64 encoded string `$file_data['content']` Instead, send the length of the decoded `$content`.

```
$content =  base64_decode($file_data['content']);
// Send the Content-length of the decoded data $content
// Should work, since strlen() is binary safe
header("Content-length: ". strlen($content));
```

Comment: Thanks for an urgent reply, I have tested it but, No Luck

Answer (score 0):

> why is it so[?]

You have stored some data into the database. On retrieval, you didn't get the original data back. That's why.

What is causing this? There can be numerous things that cause this. From the information you've outlined in your question I can only guess:

- Wrong length given (in your case the save-as process might expect more bytes then send and pads the file with NULL-bytes or something else esoteric).
- Wrong data given. The data you retrieved from the database might not be the original data any longer due to truncation, e.g. the field you store the data into is too small to keep all the data.

Please double-check the encoding/decoding part of your code (test it!) and ensure that the [database column has a fitting type<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html) as well to store your data. Compare the length of the original content with the length you retrieve from the database. Additionally you could add a checksum (e.g. [`md5`](http://php.net/md5)) for your data to test if it was changed or not.

Comment: When I retrieve text file it works fine but whenever I go for binary files it gives me such hard times.

Comment: How large (in bytes) is that image data in question originally? `base64-encode` will even make it larger. And there are limits of size next to the column, e.g. for the communication with the databse. I suggest you first of all remove the base64 encoding because the LONGBLOB datatype stores binary data perfectly well.

Comment: I have just tested one thing but, don't know why it's happening that the image i am uploading is of 680KB but the image i am downloading is of 698 KB